# Azure Storage Service Rest APIs: Constructing Signature String(stringToSign) dynamically with the given URI input in java

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-queues, azure-storage-files

Is there a way to construct a **stringToSign** String dynamically for any given azure storage rest API with the given URI input in java?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key